# Custom Handler makes Blender crash when rendering

Tags: python

I am working on a script that works with a `Handlers.frame_change_post`.

Basically, the script puts lines from a text file into a List. Collects all the markers into an other list. And manages to make subtitles out of all this. The caption is updated at every frame.

It works very well and surprisingly fast but, when I render, I notice that all the markers are blinkering and then, after a random number of frames, Blender crashes. *Before flaging my post as off-topic and bug report, please hear my question :*

No matter if it's a bug or not, I'd like to find a better way to achieve what the script does. Is it really sane to run this piece of code 25 times per second? I mean, if I were Blender, I would crash all the same ! ;-)

The full script includes a timecode, working with the same handler and modifying a text object. This works fine.

Here's a stripped piece of script to give the idea :

```
#the text object (3D)
now = bpy.data.objects['sub']
#the list of markers (lines start and end)
sub = []
#the list of markers that initiate a new line
sub_start = []
#the text file
bpy.types.Scene.sub_file = 'English'
List = []
```

...
...
...

```
def update_markers():     
    sub[:] = []
    sub_start[:] = []
    for m in bpy.context.scene.timeline_markers:
        sub.append(m.frame)
        if m.name == 'start':
            sub_start.append(m.frame)
    sub.sort(key=lambda tup: tup)
    sub_start.sort()      

def find_nearest(a,frame):
# here I try to find the closest < marker to the current frame
    if frame > a[0]:
        f = max([x for x in a if x <= frame])
        try:
            # test if the marker also belongs to the start list
            idx = sub_start.index(f)
        except ValueError:
            return -1
        else:
            return idx
    else:
        return -1

def sub_line(frame):
    idx = find_nearest(sub, frame)
    if idx > -1:
        now = List[idx]  
        return [now]  
    else:
        return ['']  

def update_text(self):
    if len(List) > 0:
        now.data.body = sub_line(bpy.context.scene.frame_current)


#---------------- MAIN -----------------------------
update_markers()
update_caption_list()
now.data.body = ''
#---------------------------------------------------


def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(update_text)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(update_text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

If someone has a piece of advice or any idea to prevent Blender from freaking out, I would be thrilled ! Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't use `bpy.context` in handlers, Not sure this is the bug, but you should use the argument to the handler (self) in your case.

Comment: Also - since you are asking about Blender behaving incorrectly, it really helps if you provide a way for someone else to redo the problem. Just looking at the script, Im not sure whats wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! You are right, here's a link to the project files : http://habanita.org/test_caption_machine.zip (59Mo)

Comment: @Nikos_VSE if you have found a solution please write an answer